# Mysql - Group By start and end times within 30 minutes

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to summarize employees time off from our timekeeping application and am needing to combine records if the start and end times are the same or within 30 minutes.

This is what my data looks like:

```
First_Name    Start_Date             End_Date
EmployeeA     2015-07-23 08:00:00    2015-07-23 16:30:00
EmployeeB     2015-07-23 12:00:00    2015-07-23 08:00:00
EmployeeC     2015-08-20 08:00:00    2015-08-20 10:15:00
EmployeeC     2015-08-20 10:15:00    2015-08-20 12:00:00
EmployeeC     2015-08-20 12:30:00    2015-08-20 16:30:00
EmployeeD     2015-08-22 08:00:00    2015-08-22 10:15:00
EmployeeD     2015-08-22 16:00:00    2015-08-22 16:30:00
```

In the example above what I want my output to look like is:

```
First_Name    Start_Date             End_Date
EmployeeA     2015-07-23 08:00:00    2015-07-23 16:30:00
EmployeeB     2015-07-23 12:00:00    2015-07-23 08:00:00
EmployeeC     2015-08-20 08:00:00    2015-08-20 16:30:00
EmployeeD     2015-08-22 08:00:00    2015-08-22 09:00:00
EmployeeD     2015-08-22 16:00:00    2015-08-22 16:30:00
```

Essentially any records whos end time is within 30 minutes or equal to the start time of another records for the same employee the entry should be grouped.

What I have so far is a group by that combines records if there times are within a 24 hour time period, however this will combine the records in my example for EmployeeD which is not my intention.

```
select a.first_name, start_date, max(end_date)
from timeoff
group by unix_timestamp(start_date) DIV 17200, first_name
```

I think I need to use both the start and end times in the group by function but need help in determining how to do so.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: sounds like your system is messed up !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that is not the purpose of the group by directive. I would recommend doing that on whatever the language you are using along with mysql.

If you must do that on mysql a solution that come in mind would require a few changes:

- Another column to establish an trigger generated id to group by afterwards let's call it `shift_id`.
- An trigger on that table associated with post and update events to check the time difference between the row being posted/updated and the last iteration from the same employee and then setting the `shift_id` the same as the previous iteration or a new auto-generated one.

Doing so would require far more work than simple looking for it in the code of your application.

Comment: FWIW, I don't agree with this assessment.

Comment: Please elaborate. Which part you didn't agree with? And why.

Comment: While GROUP BY might not be appropriate, MySQL is perfectly capable of handling this task, with no change to the schema.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations Strawberry to accomplish what I need?  If GROUP BY is not adequate I am willing to try any other method.